# What sensor can be used to detect rotation when upright?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Hi I am creating an application in which the user holds the phone upright and then rotates it around the y axis (similar to taking a panorama). [image: y axis]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Art/gyro_rotation_2x.png))</sub>

I need to detect the angle of rotation. In iOS this was fairly simple with the gyroscope sensor, but I am not finding the same luck with Android. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Y axis points to the center of earth, the value you are looking for is called azimuth.

To monitor its change you will need to register a listener for TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD events:

```
mngr = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

accelerometer = mngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
magneticField = mngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

int rate = SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME; // or other
mngr.registerListener(sensorListener, accelerometer, rate);
mngr.registerListener(sensorListener, magneticField, rate);
```

And within the listener, call:

```
  float[] values = new float[3];
  SensorManager.getOrientation(R, values);
  float current_azimuth_val = values[0]; // <----------
```

Note that the quality. and latency, if the data you will obtain is highly hardware dependent.

Comment: What is the 'R' value in getOrientation()? Thanks.

Comment: your answer would lead to an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

There are various sensors available that can be managed through a SensorManager.  Of course, since every device decides whether or not to put a particular sensor on the hardware platform for their model you have to check whether one exists.  Some have gyro like iOS, some can be done with accelerometer and magnometer sensors in its place.

You can get started here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html